# AWS Use Generated iOS SDK produces EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services

This bug has stopped us for quite some while, and now I hope someone here has some suggestions, as the AWS support was not able to help so far. We are using a use generated swift SDK from AWS. Everything works just fine until we get a result. The result itself is printable in a unit test, but trying to access any properties of the result leads to an empty memory address and produces a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

The code below shows a working AWSTask which has a custom AWSModel response. Printing only the result works fine, but trying to access any properties of the result produces said error.

```
task.continueWith { (response) -> Any? in
        if let error = response.error {
            // Error is nil
        } else if let result = response.result {

            // Prints the property as intended to the console
            print(result)

            // Produces a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error
            print(result.property)
        }
        return nil
    }
```

All used Classes should be correct, as the same code works in other generated SDKs without the problem. The project configuration should be correct aswell, because other generated SDKs work without problem in the same project.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the `generated AWS SDK` ?  This is not the offcial AWS SDK from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ios/index.html#lang/en_us ?

Comment: @SébastienStormacq It is a auto generated swift SDK for the API Gateway as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-ios-swift.html

Comment: Ah OK. I got it.  The SDK is standard.  The autogenerated part are the parts specific to your API  :-)  I will have a look deeper in details.

Comment: @SébastienStormacq just let me know what details you need, and I will do my best to give you the information